# How can i free the pointer i used? is it possible to free pointers after use?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

void trimSpace(char *s) {

    char *t = s;

    while(s = t, t[0] == ' '){ //checks initial array is space
      while (*(s) = *(s+1),*s++ != '\0') { . //if so then move all data to left
      }
    }
    printf("%s",s);
    //free(s);
    //free(t);
}

int main(){
    char s[] = "  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    trimSpace(s);

    return 0;
}
```

is it possible to free the pointers. i am getting 
ERROR: Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
(Stopped running after the first error. Please fix your code.)

Comment: No malloc, no free.  If a pointer is not loaded with the address of a block allocated with malloc, (and derivatves like calloc, strdup), you must not attempt to free it.

Comment: You don't free pointers, you free allocated memory that pointers point to.

Answer (score 2):

The `free` function is used to deallocate memory that was returned from `malloc` and return it to the heap's available space.  Only a pointer returned from `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` may be passed to `free`.

You're not allocating memory dynamically, so no need to call `free`.

Comment: @MikeH Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable capable of storing an address of another variable i.e. it is like other variables. Static memory allocation is done at compile time and stack is used to manage this. As soon as the scope of variable is over, memory is freed. Only the dynamic memory allocated during runtime using heap can be freed using the free() function